# AngularJS ng-repeat for dynamic child json array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, json, html, angularjs-ng-repeat

I'm having a dynamic JSON, which contains the list of name, it also contains the children names as a subset. How can I show it in the HTML UI using angularJS ng-repeat

The Sample Dynamic JSON is

```
$scope.family = [
   {
      "name":"Siva",
      "child":[
         {
            "name":"Suriya"
         },
         {
            "name":"Karthick"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Kumar",
      "child":[
         {
            "name":"Rajini"
         },
         {
            "name":"Kamal"
         },
         {
            "name":"Ajith"
         }
      ]
   },
   {
      "name":"Samer"
   },
   {
      "name":"Mahesh"
   }
];
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="members in family">
    <!-- How to Show it in the UI -->
</div>
```

> Note: The JSON is generated based on Request. The Child array is
>   Optional and it may contain the length 'n'

Comment: Its not a valid JSON.

Comment: @Rajesh I Updated the JSON...

Comment: You can try something like this: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/U3pVM/22375/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Corrected answer

```
<ul ng-repeat="member in family">
    <li>{{member.name}}
        <ul>
            <li ng-bind="c.name" ng-repeat="c in member.child"></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can better your answer by adding an `ng-if` directive, as the `child` is *optional*. Of course, it won't make any impact to you app, but it is a good way to code.

Plus, instead of adding `ng-repeat` on `ul`, it should be in `li`. It makes no sense in looping the `ul` for a single list.

Please refer the sample [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kacjt2w7/).

**HTML:**

```
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="test">
    <ul ng-repeat="member in family">
        <li>
            {{member.name}}
            <span ng-if="member.child.length > 0">
                <ul>
                    <li ng-repeat="c in member.child">{{c.name}}</li>
                </ul>
            </span>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('test', function ($scope) {
    $scope.family = [
       {
           "name": "Siva",
           "child": [
              {
                  "name": "Suriya"
              },
              {
                  "name": "Karthick"
              }
           ]
       },
       {
           "name": "Kumar",
           "child": [
              {
                  "name": "Rajini"
              },
              {
                  "name": "Kamal"
              },
              {
                  "name": "Ajith"
              }
           ]
       },
       {
           "name": "Samer"
       },
       {
           "name": "Mahesh"
       }
    ];
});
```